# Keep Github Pages and Hugo output in same directory?

Tags: configuration, jekyll, github-pages, symlink, hugo

I recently decided to generate a Github Pages website using Hugo. I wanted to keep Hugo input (configuration, themes) in the same directory as the output, for easy management. Unfortunately, Github Pages's CI complains when I try to turn `public` directory into a symlink into `.`, as well as when I create a `hugo` directory and make `hugo/public` a symlink to `..`. Are there any other options to keep configs and output in the same directory, bypassing that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting the following in my config.toml file:

```
publishDir = "."
```

As a result, I didn't need the "public" directory pointing to `.`.